# subs(), replace(), xreplace() not working in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I want to simplify an expresion in sympy, i want to replace/ substitute the term j_nu/a_nu for S_nu but no matter what function I use it doesn't replace it and always prints the old expresion.

this is what I have

```
tau_s, a_nu, dS, S_nu, d_tau, S, dI_nu, I_nu, j_nu = sym.symbols('tau_s a_nu dS S_nu d\\tau S dI_nu I_nu j_nu')
dI_nu = (-a_nu*I_nu + j_nu)*dS
dI_nu
# defining the left side as I 
I = dI_nu 
# defining a second expresion 
I1 = a_nu
#simplifying
I2 = sym.cancel(I/I1)
I3 = sym.expand(I2)
I3
#getting rid of ds
# desaciendonos de dS
Ids = sym.expand(sym.cancel(I3/dS))
Ids
#Here is were I tried replacing j_nu/a_nu for S_nu using the functions mentioned at the begining but it didn't work
I4 = (-I_nu + (j_nu/a_nu)).subs((j_nu / a_nu) , S_nu)
I4
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. After running your code, `I4` outputs `-I_nu + S_nu`. I ran it on https://live.sympy.org/, so I assume that is the most recent version of sympy.

Comment: I confirm @jared findings. Everything works as expected on SymPy 1.12

Answer (score 0):

Try rearranging to not use a compound `old` expression:

```py
I4 = (-I_nu + (j_nu/a_nu)).subs(j_nu, a_nu*S_nu)
```